# C++ template functions and includes

Tags: c++, templates, include

I am writing a class with template functions, and trying to get rid of includes in the .h file by moving them into the .cpp file.

The declaration of my class looks like:

```
// myclass.h
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>

class MyClass{
    ...
    template<class T> void my_function(const T& t){
        std::ostringstream os;
        {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
            oa & t;
        }
        do_something(os);
    }
}
```

Given that I use a template method, where T could be anything, I have to provide the definition in the header. Is it possible to refactor this code (by defining a helper function I suppose) to enable moving the

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
```

into the .cpp file?

Many thanks

Comment: you can do that if you explicitly instantiate the template into the cpp file

Comment: For unbounded `T`, no. If you only need to support a limited number of types, David’s comment is the answer.

Comment: Indeed, if the set of possible T was known I could instantiate the template in the cpp file. Here it's unfortunately not the case.

Comment: Why is it a problem leaving the `#include` in `myclass.h`?

Comment: @iavr probably long recompilation times, it's often better to move stuff in the cpp files. Makes life easier even with precompiled headers. Might not be the case here

Comment: long compilation times, entangled libraries, ... I guess it's good practice to minimize the number of headers in the .h file when possible.

Comment: Yes, even possible circular dependencies can be minimized by that in some weird cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short story: you can if you know the types you're going to use in advance and explicitly instantiate them into the cpp file.

As Konrad noted, if your *T* is unbound there's no way that I know to accomplish it.

Notice that moving .h files into the cpp files may be a good practice to avoid long recompilation times if those headers change (and other common issues), but in the case above (a boost header) it's unlikely that it's going to change so it might not be needed at all from a compile time point of view.

Comment: I hoped I could get away with it by using pimpl, but that doesn't seem possible either. Anyway, thanks for your help!